# Space-time metric in tensor form

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

In space time metric in tensor form:

The distance is given by $$ds^2=c^2dt-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2$$

Which in tensor form is: $$ds^2=\sum_{\alpha \beta}g_{\alpha \beta}dx^\alpha dx^\beta$$

Using Einstein summation convention  we have $$ds^2=g_{\alpha \beta}dx^\alpha dx^\beta$$

I was wondering what the explict form of this looks like:

I know that:

> [image: Blockquote]

I was wonder that $dx^\alpha$ and $dx^\beta$ look like?

All together does it look like this:

> [image: Blockquote]

(i know the above is wrong becuase it is invalid matrix)

Comment: Please note that posting images of math is very strongly discouraged (even downvoted).  Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the fact that $g_{\alpha \beta} dx^{\alpha} = dx_{\beta}$ where $dx^{\alpha}$ is the column vector you have in your above expression, then $dx_{\beta}$ would be the row vector $(cdt,-dx,-dy,-dz)$. Then, the line element becomes $ds^{2} = dx_{\beta}dx^{\beta}$ which is a row vector multiplying a column vector, giving you a scalar and not a matrix.

Equivalently, you can view $g_{\mu \nu} dx^{\mu} dx^{\nu}$ as $\vec{dx}^{T} \cdot \textbf{g}\cdot \vec{dx}$ which gives a scalar and not a matrix.